# Ag-Grid Basic AngularJS 1.x Example Not Working

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

The code from [official website](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angularjs-data-grid/?framework=angularjs#gsc.tab=0) is not working, getting blank at [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xaR6RwwnaJS0zrJEspx8?p=preview), only two places modified:

1. script.js, `var module = angular.module` to `var m = angular.module`
   as Plnkr complains about "Redefinition of module".
2. index.html, explicitly declare height for gridOptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `<script src="scripts.js"></script>` when your file is named `script.js`

Make sure the file reference is the same as in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tMBTKmaFzws1ufDqJ8Jd?p=preview)

As a side note, it is best to debug your applications by tackling the errors in the order that they appear, sometimes fixing the 404 not found will fix anything that angular wants to complain about...